# Need design Idea on Camel Route

Tags: spring-boot, timer, routes, apache-camel, scheduler

I have a situation where Timer or scheduler needs to wake up every 30 mins
After it wakes up it needs to run a query and Fetch queue names through a query , the max queues are 24 but at a time only 4 to 5 queues will be busy . So it needs to connect to only these 4 or 5 queues and fetch the records update the status based on correlation id obtained in Header and then close the completed routes and restart the process again.
currently i have used a for loop to loop from all the queues and send to "direct:syncQueues"
and another route which reads from "direct:syncQueues" and updates the Database .
how can i design such a Route
i have tried Spring @Scheduler through a component but dont know how to call this route from Scheduler. i also need to make sure how to close those opened routes.

My current implementation looks like this
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

```
List<String> sources messagepubservice.getSourceQNames();

for(String uri: sources){
from(uri).process(exchange -> {
ThreaqdContext.pout(ApplicationInfo.TRACE_ID,exchange.getExchangeId());
}).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Direct Sync Queues", "MQ Message(publishOutboundMessage) received:${body}").to("direct:syncQueues");
}

from("direct:syncQueues").process(exchange->{

///do the processing and store to DB by getting values from Header and body


}
}
```

Comment: i need to start a timer and then read from a JMS queue , these queues can we dynamic which come from a db table.

Comment: is it a good design to connect to 20 queues in apache camel ?